# Please explain Mac Lane notation on page 48

Tags: category-theory

On page 47-48 of Mac Lane's book on Category theory, he uses the notation $\mathbb C^{d_0}$ to denote the functor $\mathbb C^2\to \mathbb C$, defined by $(a:A\to B)\mapsto A$, which takes an arrow to its domain. Can somebody please explain that notation. Mac Lane himself refers to "the end of the last section", but I didn't find there a clear definition.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{E}$ (small) categories. Let $F : \mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{E}$ be a functor. $\mathcal{C}^F : \mathcal{C}^{\mathbb{E}}\to\mathcal{C}^{\mathbb{D}}$ and is defined by $G \mapsto G \circ F$. In this scenario Mac Lane is using, $d_0 : \mathbf1 \to \mathbf 2$ and so $\mathcal{C}^{d_0} : \mathcal{C}^{\mathbf{2}}\to\mathcal{C}^{\mathbf{1}}$. Mac Lane then tacitly uses the equivalence $\mathcal{C}\simeq\mathcal{C}^{\mathbf{1}}$.

An arrow in $\mathcal{C}$ can be identified a functor $\mathbf{2}\to\mathcal{C}$ and an object of $\mathcal{C}$ can be identified with a functor $\mathbf{1}\to\mathcal{C}$. You should work out the details of this if you haven't yet.

More generally, this exponential notation is commonly used in Cartesian closed (or even more generally, monoidally closed) categories.

Comment: Is this definition in Mac Lane's book? Does this kind of a functor has a name?

Comment: This is defined on page 44 (as Mac Lane said). It's the functorial action of the exponential functor. It could also be described as the action of the internal hom in some cases. If I were to "read it", I would just call it "pre-composition by $F$" or "the functor induced by pre-composing by $F$". The category of small categories is Cartesian closed, but the category of locally small categories is not. That said, you can still exponentiate a locally small category by a small category and get a locally small category.